# Empty dict as parameter default in class __init__

Tags: python, dictionary, default-value

In Python why does the class

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, _my_dict={}):
        self.my_dict = _my_dict
```

have the following very strange and undesired behaviour:

```
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.my_dict['greet'] ="hallo"
>>> b = MyClass()
>>> b.my_dict['greet'] ="ciao"
>>> 
>>> print(a.my_dict)
{'greet': 'ciao'}
>>> print(b.my_dict)
{'greet': 'ciao'}
```

Note: I know I can fix this by using `None` as `_my_dict` default in the `__init__` method:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, _my_dict=None):
        if _my_dict is None:
            self.my_dict = {}
        else:
            self.my_dict = _my_dict
```

So the problem lies clearly with the '{}' as the default for `_my_dict`: It seems to refer in both instantiations to the *same* object. **But why is this so?** And is there a tighter solution than mine with the cumbersome if statement?

Comment: That's actually the idiomatic solution.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for answering my second question with your comment. I feared that this is true...

Comment: You can use a conditional expression to cut down on the clunk: `self.x = x if x is not None else {}`